# Slider is not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Hi guys I have my site in: `http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/`

If you view it in IE 8, the slider is not working (collapsed between the menu and the product images section)

I used the hard coded word press theme  written by previous developer in continuing the site. So, basically, I really don't know how to troubleshoot the homepage in php. And the slider is embedded already in the theme (not a separate plugin). So my question is:

**Q: Is there any way to solve this issue using css or jquery code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Your slider use canvas wich is only availaible with HTML5 (IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera).

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: Maybe check out a library like explorer canvas? I don't know how well it works-- never used it myself. http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @L105: Thank you very much, I decided to just put an image so that at least the site has a banner in IE8. I hope the IE8 will become totally ancient soon. :D

Comment: What you can do is search for another Wordpress slider plugin wich work for IE8.